# how to set the border color to Card component in React material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

how to set the border color to Card component in React material ui .I have tried style property

style={{borderColor:"red"}} in code  but it won't work. Is there any Solution?

Answer (score 6):

What you're doing works, the problem is that you can't see a border without width nor style (solid, dashed, etc).

Try using
`style={{ border: "1px solid red" }}`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the borderColor prop on it like this:

```
<Box borderColor="primary.main">…
<Box borderColor="secondary.main">…
<Box borderColor="error.main">…
<Box borderColor="grey.500">…
<Box borderColor="text.primary">…
```

And the border size with the border prop like this:

```
<Box border={0}>…
```

See full API here:
https://material-ui.com/system/borders/

Comment: Downvoting because the question specifically asks about the `Card` component, not the `Box` component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `border` CSS property on the `Card` component to set the color.

```
<Card sx={{ border: '1px solid red' }}>
  <Typography variant='body1'>This has red borders</Typography>
</Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

just it:

```
<Card sx={{ borderColor: 'red' }}>
  <Typography variant='body2'>This has red borders</Typography>
</Card>
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.